# estimation for the error for ODE with $y_{n+1}=y_n+h_n \cdot\phi(t_n,y_n), t_{n+1}=t_n+h_n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the IVP $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(0)=y_0$, a solution $y:[0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and a stable one-step method $y_{n+1}=y_n+h_n \cdot\phi_f(t_n,y_n), t_{n+1}=t_n+h_n$ with $h_n=h=T/n$ and $\mathcal T_h=\{t_0<t_1,...,<t_n=T\}$. Suppose $\phi_f$ is Lipschitz continuous and has the consistency estimate $|\tau_h|\leq Ch^p$ for all $h>0$. Suppose that there is an absolute error of $\epsilon>0$ in each step of the numerical procedure. Find an $C>0$ (dependent on $h$ and $\epsilon$) such that $\sup\limits_{t_i\in \mathcal T_h}|y_i-y(t_i)|\leq C$. 
I need a hint how to start here because I don't know how I can use the absolute error.

Comment: You should find and solve a recursive inequality $e_{n+1}\le (1+Lh)e_n+\tau_h+ϵ$

Comment: @LutzLehmann is $e_{n+1}=\sup |y(t_{n+1})-y_{n+1}|$?

Comment: That depends on what the domain for the supremum is. In general $e_n=\|y_n-y(t_n)\|$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann $e_{n}=\sup\limits_{t_n\in \mathcal T_h}|y_n-y(t_n)|$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, that loses too much information to be useful. It is just the error at time $t_n$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so we have $e_n\leq \sup\limits_{n\in\mathcal T_h}|y_n-y(t_n)|$?

Comment: Yes, that is true. You can find an exponential bound for the sequence of errors, the last one will also be the maximal one. The exact errors can oscillate and thus be substantially smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$
\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}-\Phi_f(t,y(t),h)=\tau(t)=O(h^p).
$$
The computer realization of the numerical method proceeds as
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+h\Phi_f(t_n,y_n,h)+ϵ_n
$$
For the difference $e_n=\|y_n-y(t_n)\|$ one thus gets
$$
e_{n+1}\le e_n+hL_\Phi e_n+ϵ_n+\tau_n\le e^{hL_\Phi}e_n+ϵ_n+hτ_n
$$
This is a linear recursion inequality
$$
e_{n+1}\le qe_n+r, ~~~q=1+L_\Phi h,~~r=ϵ+hτ_h,
$$
which can be solved easily with several approaches.

For instance distributing $r$ to get a geometric sequence
$$
e_{n+1}+\frac{r}{q-1}=q·\left(e_n+\frac{r}{q-1}\right)
$$
can now easily be solved as
$$
e_n+\frac{r}{q-1}\le q^n·\left(e_0+\frac{r}{q-1}\right)\\~\\
e_n\le r\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}\le(ϵ+hτ_h)\frac{e^{L_\Phi(nh)}-1}{L_\Phi h}
$$